# Project dependency in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I have two C++ projects - Gui.vcproj and Dll.vcproj.

Gui is an application and Dll produces a DLL.

What's the best way to make the dependency resolution automatic?

I tried adding Dll.vcproj into Gui.vcproj's references, but it doesn't seem working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Create a solution
- Add Gui.vcproj and Dll.vcproj to the solution
- From solution explorer window, right click the solution yuo just created.
- Choose Project dependencies.
- Select the project you want of these two, and check the 'Depends on' check box.

Comment: thanks a lot. What's the difference between "Project Dependency" and "References" in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Put both projects into a common solution and specify "Project dependencies" in the solution properties. That's exactly what "Project dependencies" are for.